# How do I fix a transparent menu on a image?

Tags: html, css, menu, transparent

I am trying to fix a few issues in my code, but somehow it seems to get worse.

It should look like the example. The four boxes need to sit next to each other. All six images have to be in in row of three. for that I used div class column. On these images the names of the animal should be written (transparent). 
For this I used Pad. Now the names appear on the background image instead of the individual images under.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("images/mandarinfish.jpg");

  /* Full height */
  height: 50%; 

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

/* bovenste rand*/
header {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
    
#grade {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  background-image: linear-gradient(grey, white, grey);     
}

ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;   
}

ul li{
   float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;  
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
}

ul li a:hover{
    background-color:gainsboro;
}

  /* positie navbar */
  position: relative;
}    
    
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/*menu*/
.container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 90px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

 .navbar
{
    background-color: transparent
}

/*blok categorie*/
.box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black ;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 500;
  height: 100;
}

/*size foto's*/
 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

/* three equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/*onderste zes afbeeldingen tekst op foto */
 
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; 
   text-align: center;
   color: transparent;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img { 
   border:2px solid #000000;
}
 
footer {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
 
/* Tablet Landscape */
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    #primary { width:67%; }
    #secondary { width:30%; margin-left:3%;}  
}

/* Tabled Portrait */
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    #primary { width:100%; }
    #secondary { width:100%; margin:0; border:none; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
   <head>
      <title>Dieren</title>
      <link href="normalise.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="dieren.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
      </header>
       <div class="bg"></div>
        <div class="bg-img">
         <div class="scrollmenu">
            <div class="container">
               <div class="topnav">
                  <ul>
                      <li><a>Amfibie&eumln</a></li>
                      <li><a>Vogels</a></li>
                      <li><a>Vissen</a></li>
                      <li><a>Zoogdieren</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>      
         <div class="box2">
             <h1>Kikker</h1> 
             <p>Categorie Amfibie&eumln</p>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
             <h1>Bosui</h1>
             <p>Categorie vogels</p>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
             <h1>Siamese Kempvis</h1> 
             <p>Categorie vissen</p>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
             <h1>Eekhoorn</h1> 
             <p>Categorie zoogdieren</p>
         </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                <img src="images/clownfish.jpg" alt="clown vis" style="width: 100%"/>
                    <div class="centered">Clown vis</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column">
                   <img src="images/eagle.jpg" alt="adelaar" style="width: 100%">
                    <div class="centered">Adelaar</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column">
                   <img src="images/elephants.jpg" alt="olifant" style="width: 100%">
                    <div class="centered">Olifant</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column">
                   <img src="images/Yellowbanded.jpg" alt="kikker" style="width: 100%">
                   <div class="centered">Kiker</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column">
                   <img src="images/peacock.jpg" alt="pauw" style="width: 100%">
                   <div class="centered">Pauw</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column">
                   <img src="images/toad.jpg" alt="pad" style="width: 100%">
                    <div class="centered">Pad</div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            
               
            <footer>Deze pagina is gemaakt voor opdracht 4 van HTML5 &amp; CSS.</footer>
            
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us9bn.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFRuK.jpg The correct example

[Current Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us9bn.png) My code sorry I cant add my images so you won't see the result with the right images.

Comment: You're probably going to want to look into 'css grid'. It is going to take a fair bit of restructuring from your current code to achieve the result you're after, but grid will help you do this.

Answer (score 0):

check this , remove some css code for better view , for text you can add text-shadow too

changes:

add display: flex; to bg class , and .topnav{align-self: flex-end;width:100%;background: rgb(255,255,255);background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.6839869736957283) 35%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5943511193539917) 100%);}

you should put topnav div inside bg div

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://natgeo.imgix.net/subjects/headers/Animal-Tigers.jpg?auto=compress,format&w=1920&h=960&fit=crop");

  /* Full height */
  height: 50%; 

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  z-index:100;
  display: flex;
}

/* bovenste rand*/
header {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
    
#grade {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  background-image: linear-gradient(grey, white, grey);     
}

ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;   
}
ul li{
   float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: .8;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;  
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
}
ul li a:hover{
    background-color:gainsboro;
}

  /* positie navbar */
  position: relative;
}    
    
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/*menu*/
.container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 90px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
 .navbar
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
.topnav{
      align-self: flex-end;
  width:100%;
  background: rgb(255,255,255);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.6839869736957283) 35%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5943511193539917) 100%);
 
}

/*blok categorie*/
.box2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black ;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 500;
  height: 100;
}

/*size foto's*/
 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

/* three equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/*onderste zes afbeeldingen tekst op foto */
 
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; 
   text-align: center;
   color: transparent;
}

/* .centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
} */

img { 
   border:2px solid #000000;
}
 
footer {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

 
/* Tablet Landscape */
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    #primary { width:67%; }
    #secondary { width:30%; margin-left:3%;}  
}

/* Tabled Portrait */
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    #primary { width:100%; }
    #secondary { width:100%; margin:0; border:none; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
   <head>
      <title>Dieren</title>
      <link href="normalise.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="dieren.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
      </header>
      <div class="bg">
        <div class="topnav">
                  <ul>
                      <li><a>Amfibie&eumln</a></li>
                      <li><a>Vogels</a></li>
                      <li><a>Vissen</a></li>
                      <li><a>Zoogdieren</a></li>
                  </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
      <div class="bg-holder">
        
     </div>
       
        <div class="bg-img">
         <div class="scrollmenu">
            <div class="container">
              
            </div>
         </div>      
         <div class="box2">
             <h1>Kikker</h1> 
             <p>Categorie Amfibie&eumln</p>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
             <h1>Bosui</h1>
             <p>Categorie vogels</p>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
             <h1>Siamese Kempvis</h1> 
             <p>Categorie vissen</p>
         </div>
         <div class="box2">
             <h1>Eekhoorn</h1> 
             <p>Categorie zoogdieren</p>
         </div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                <img src="images/clownfish.jpg" alt="clown vis" style="width: 100%"/>
                    <div class="centered">Clown vis</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column">
                   <img src="images/eagle.jpg" alt="adelaar" style="width: 100%">
                    <div class="centered">Adelaar</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column">
                   <img src="images/elephants.jpg" alt="olifant" style="width: 100%">
                    <div class="centered">Olifant</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column">
                   <img src="images/Yellowbanded.jpg" alt="kikker" style="width: 100%">
                   <div class="centered">Kiker</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column">
                   <img src="images/peacock.jpg" alt="pauw" style="width: 100%">
                   <div class="centered">Pauw</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="column">
                   <img src="images/toad.jpg" alt="pad" style="width: 100%">
                    <div class="centered">Pad</div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            
               
            <footer>Deze pagina is gemaakt voor opdracht 4 van HTML5 &amp; CSS.</footer>
            
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>[enter image description here][1]
</html>
```